# Which is the most efficient method to store and use data loaded from database in a web page?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have a website which has a lot of `combo boxes` and `auto-complete` `textboxes`, that take in data from the database masters.

I don't want the data to be loaded each time a user enter logs in, or the page refreshes.

What would be the most efficient and secure and fastest method to load and store data for the client.Also consider a medium sized database.

I tried a few things like,

1. Storing in a `Javascript` array- Its lost once the user refreshes.
2. Including `Servlets` to load data and fill in on the page, that too has
   same problem with refreshing.
3. Using `ajax` and filling when ever required.
4. Storing the data on `server side` by loading it once,this saves me
   the querying the database everytime. But with every logout/login it
   has to be maintained.

Is there a method better than this

P.S. Try not to make this too subjective, Please reply only the methods with a brief description of it.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve by avoiding database queries?

Comment: I trying to reduce the delay created due to fetching and loading the data to the page while website page loads. Querying everytime takes longer for me to load the the page.

Comment: Your application data has to be stored/maintained at server side, which should be transferred to client side for displaying, whenever the client requests it. The data in server side, can be cached(to say `memcached`), so that you don't hit database for every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Here's a [demo](http://people.w3.org/mike/localstorage.html)!

And a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/).

Comment: html local storage stores data in the browser and it will be available even after you have logged out of your webpage. Isn't that a security concern? All your data in the client browser ?

Comment: Dont think so, since the data that will be stored will be users data in his/her browser.

Comment: @Virendra does this load the entire combo-box data or does it only allow to store in the key-value format. I am looking for a method that has the entire combo-box data withing it.

Comment: You can store any object in Web Storage, as long as you can stringify it.

Comment: If the data is sensitive(in this case looks like it as OP mentions user login), then HTML5 local storage is not a good idea. There is good explanation in [HTML5 localStorage security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718349/html5-localstorage-security)

Comment: @Chandra: No I am not intending to store sensitive data. Its like the combo-box of list of the institutions/services etc.

Comment: @VirendraRajput How long does the browser hold the data and what is its scope?

Comment: The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

Comment: and you can clear it anytime you want by using this "localStorage.clear();"

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 local storage should work fine for you, however, if you like this to work across older browsers that do not support HTML5 take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/

I have used it before in different applications and it works great. Also, why not use good old cookies?

Answer (score 0):

It also depend on your setup that queries and loads the data. ASP.NET has some very good built in caching which can be set so avoiding the whole issue.

Ultimately, in anyone given project I find I use a few different options;
from `page caching` (so the server caches the page output),
to using `session cookies` to hold certain data which can be carried around the site,
to `persistant cookies` if needed,
Certain data suits being carried around by `QueryStrings`,
with some suiting an `ajax` or `json` setup to get the data on demand,
finally some just suiting a vanilla query and load into the page.

With all these at your disposal, it's a case of picking the right tool for the job. A 200 character string isn't suitable to be passed in a `QueryString`. If it's only use once on one page, then putting it in a `session cookie` could be suitable. If it's going to be updated frequently, then probably an `ajax` / `json` call would be better.

An `ID` however would lend itself better to being passed in a `QueryString`, along with form values (say the index of dropdownlists), etc, etc.

As a final note, it's worth checking how long these queries to the database are taking, as you could be putting in a lot of effort for milliseconds of returns.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 local storage seems to be a good solution, but if HTML5 is not an option for you i did something similar as you are trying to do in the past by simply serializing options and save it into cookies.