# Secure Storage on a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On Chrome's [developer page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) about storage in extensions, it explicitly says that the storage area is not encrypted, so confidential information should not be stored there.

Safari offers a "[SafariExtensionSecureSettings](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SafariExtensionSecureSettings/SafariExtensionSecureSettings/SafariExtensionSecureSettings.html)" class to securely store key/value pairs. Is there an equivalent in Google Chrome?

Comment: I've seen some questions remotely similar to this where people have made the suggestion to encrypt the confidential information and then use localStorage, but I'm looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no equivalent in Google Chrome to Safari's "SafariExtensionSecureSettings".

Here is another answer that outlines security in localStorage more generally https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719435/117068

Comment: The Credential Management API? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/

Comment: In chrome that is not supported for extensions