# How to safely store a password with jQM and PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am making a jQM and PhoneGap app.

I am wondering how can I safely store some data I need to use multiple times in multiple sessions. Is there any other possibility than localStorage or Database? Which way is most efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut reaction is that localStorage is not secure and this other answer seems to confirm that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719435/1751392

I think Krishnan's closing point rings true:

"*If it needs to be secure, its best to not send it to the client. What is not in your control can never be secure.*"

I'm not sure what secure data you're handling but is there any chance you could perform the operations on a server-side application via web-service? That would probably be the most secure option. The bottom line is that a client-side app will never be totally secure (at least in my opinion).

I can't comment on the security of a PhoneGap database solution since I don't have enough experience in that department.

Comment: I want to store login and password on client side, so I could enable auto login. Do you have any expierience in thjis matter?

Comment: I don't have any direct experience but I'm pretty up on my computer security - maybe you could validate them with the server on their first login then pass them back a security token that they can use to login next time. The token is bound to the device and only valid for X days, etc.