# HTML5 Web Storage and Web SQL Database

Tags: sql, html, local-storage

Is it possible to store the information in both Web Storage and Web SQL forever because it deletes the information after the user clears the browsing data. if its not possible what should i do to fix it

Comment: Store the information in a server. Obviously if the user wants to delete their own data there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store information in websql and web storage forever. It is not suggested to store any critical data  in these storage and rather any data stored in these storage should be synchronized with server db .

Comment: "suggested" where? Can you please add a source?

Comment: @mabi sure bro..here is the link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718349/html5-localstorage-security have fun!