# how to keep user authenticated after refreshing the page in nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I'm using laravel passport for API's and nuxt.js for frontend after a successful login if I refresh the page the user is not authenticated anymore and `loggedIn` returns false, its my first nuxt.js project so I have no idea how to deal with that, any advise is appreciated

`login.vue`

```html
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    }
  },
  methods:{
    async login(){
      const succesfulLogin = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        },
      })
      this.$store.commit("saveUser",succesfulLogin.data)
      this.$store.commit("saveToken", succesfulLogin.data.token)

      if (succesfulLogin) {
        await this.$auth.setUser({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        })
        this.$router.push('/profile')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`store/index.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({
  user:{},
  token: ""
})

export const mutations = {
  saveUser(state, payload) {
    state.user=payload;
  },
  saveToken(state, token) {
    state.token= token
  }
 
}
export const actions = {
     saveUserAction({commit}, UserObject){
         commit('saveUser');
     },
     logoutUser({commit}){
        commit('logout_user')
     }
}
export const getters = {
  getUser: (state) => {
    return state.user
  },
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return state.auth.loggedIn
  },

  loggedInUser(state) {
    return state.user.user
  }
}
```

**after a successful login**
[image]

**after refreshing the page**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We  do use a global middleware right after my `auth` module authentication

`/middleware/global.js`

```js
export default async ({ app, store }) => {
  if (store?.$auth?.$state?.loggedIn) {
    if (!app.$cookies.get('gql.me_query_expiration')) {
      // do some middleware logic if you wish

      await app.$cookies.set('gql.me_query_expiration', '5min', {
        // maxAge: 20,
        maxAge: 5 * 60,
        secure: true,
      })
    }
  }
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
router: {
  middleware: ['auth', 'global'],
},
```

We're using [`cookie-universal-nuxt`](https://github.com/microcipcip/cookie-universal/tree/master/packages/cookie-universal-nuxt) for handling secure cookies quickly, working great!

While accessing or refreshing the webapp (we do redirect to the `/login` page if not authenticated) and we use this basic GraphQL configuration where the cookie is needed.

`/plugins/nuxt-apollo-config.js`

```js
export default ({ app }) => {
  const headersConfig = setContext(() => ({
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      Authorization: app.$cookies.get('auth._token.local'), // here
    },
  }))

  [...]
}
```

Checking `gql.me_query_expiration` allows us to see if the user has authenticated lately/is currently authenticated or if he needs to refresh his token.
And `auth._token.local` is our actual JWT token, provided by the `auth` module.

As told above, it is more secure to have a `secure` cookie than some `localStorage`, this is also why we are not using it

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
auth: {
  localStorage: false, // REALLY not secure, so nah
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, is using cookies in this case irrelevent to the backend? because I'm using laravel passport for authentication in the backend?

Comment: @AIB you can use whatever you want (cookie or `localStorage`) on the client to my knowledge, since this one is generated by yourself and not your actual backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use localStorage and implement it yourself e.g.:

```
  saveToken(state, token) {
    localStorage.setItem("authToken", token);
    state.token= token
  },
  saveUser(state, payload) {
    localStorage.setItem("authUser", payload);
    state.user=payload;
  },
```

And then retrieving the localStorage when initializing your store you need to do something like this:

```
export const state = () => {
  const localUser = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
  const localToken = localStorage.getItem("authUser")
  let user = {}
  let token = ""
  if (localUser) user = localUser
  if (localToken) token = localToken
  return {
    user: user,
    token: token
  }
}
```

As @mbuechmann pointed out, be aware of the security risk when storing sensitive information in localStorage. Better to use cookies for tokens, but localStorage is the 'simple' solution.

or use a package like [nuxt-vuex-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-vuex-localstorage)

Comment: Localstorage is not a proper storage for sensitive data. This answer explains it in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718349/html5-localstorage-security

Comment: @Laurens thanks, I just tried and unfortunately it didn't work, I just have now 'authToken' with a token in local storage but still with refreshing user is no more authenticated

Comment: @AIB this is not the entire solution, you also must retrieve the localStorage with `localStorage.getItem` when initializing the store, read up on how localStorage works

Comment: @mbuechmann While you are correct that localstorage is not the safest way, if you have an xss vulnerability, you have bigger problems. Read https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/oauthoidc/localstorage-xss.html. But the best way would be to use cookies instead of localstorage. You can do this with the nuxt/auth module: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/cookie

Comment: @ Laurens is using cookies in this case works with laravel passport or it is irrelevant to the backend?