# submit register form of user in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to submit this registeration form with unique names.

**First Problem** : I can't seem to map third time. The error shows **array is not iterable**.

**Second Problem** : I cant change the setArray state in (**array not empty**) **section**. I know it is synchronous but I can't seem to find a solution.

Please give me a solution of if I want to have an immediate value of state after changing setState. I'm stuck in this problem for 3 days.

```
import React from 'react';

import { Paper, Typography, TextField , Button, makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core';

import { Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import {useEffect} from 'react';

const useStyle = makeStyles((theme)=>(

    {
        formWrapper : {
            display : 'flex',
            width : '100%',
            height : '100%',
            alignItems : 'center',
            justifyContent : 'center'
        },
        paper : {
            padding : '20px',
            margin : '20px'
        },
        textfield : {
            marginLeft : '20px',
            marginBottom : '10px'
        },
        span : {
            margin: '10px',
            marginLeft : '20px'
        }

    }
))

const Register = () =>{

    const classes = useStyle();
    const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
    const [array, setArray] = React.useState([])


    const submit = (event) =>{
        const obj = {}
        event.preventDefault();
        if(array.length === 0){ // Array is empty
            if((name === null || password === null)||(name === '' || password === '')){ //check if name and password are empty
                alert('Enter username and password')
                
            }else{  // not empty then store in localstorage
                localStorage.setItem('name', name);
                localStorage.setItem('password',password);
                
                obj.id = Math.random();
                obj.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
                obj.password = localStorage.getItem('password');
                setArray(array.push(obj))
                localStorage.setItem('array',JSON.stringify(array))
                setName('');
                setPassword('')
                return alert('You are registered'); 
                
            }
        }
        else  // array not empty
        {
            if((name === null || password === null) ||(name === '' || password === '')){
                alert('Enter username and passsword');
            }

            let array2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('array')).map(user=> user.name)
            var found = array2.includes(name);
            if(found){
                alert('User name Taken')
                setName('')
                setPassword('')
            }
            else{
                localStorage.setItem('name', name);
                localStorage.setItem('password',password);
                obj.id = Math.random();
                obj.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
                obj.password = localStorage.getItem('password');
                setArray([...array,obj])
                localStorage.setItem('array',JSON.stringify(array))
                console.log(array);
                setName('');
                setPassword('')
                return alert('You are registered'); 

            }
            
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div className = {classes.formWrapper}>
                <Paper elevation={3} className = {classes.paper} >
                <Typography variant="h5" style = {{ textAlign : 'center'}}>Register</Typography>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField id="username" className={classes.textfield}  value = {name} name = "username"  label="Username" onChange = {e=>setName(e.target.value)} />
                    <br />
                    <TextField id="password" className={classes.textfield}  value = {password} name = "password"  label="Password" onChange = {e=>setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                    <br />
                    <span className ={classes.span}><Link to="/">Sign In</Link></span>
                    <br />
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" style = {{width : '100%', marginTop : '10px'}} onClick = {submit} >Register </Button>
                </form>
                </Paper>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    )
}

 
export default Register;
```

Comment: You really sure you want to save users password to localStorage and in plain text? See this conversation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718349/html5-localstorage-security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setArray(array.push(obj))` is a state mutation and `array.push` returns the new length of the array. Add an element to the array, similar to what you did in the `else` branch. React state updates are asynchronous so you can't wait for the state to update before persisting it to local storage.

```
const newArray = [...array, obj];
setArray(newArray);
localStorage.setItem('array', JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

Alternatively you should probably just enqueue the state updates and then use an `useEffect` hook to do the persisting once state is updated.

```
setArray([...array, obj]);

...

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('array', JSON.stringify(array));
}, [array]);
```

#### Update

Since you are persisting local state to localStorage then you will want to also initialize the local state from localStorage. Use a lazy state initializer function to read in from localStorage and return the initial state value.

```
const [array, setArray] = React.useState(() => {
  const initialState = localStorage.getItem('array');
  return JSON.parse(initialState) || [];
});
```

If `JSON.parse(initialState)` returns a value then this will be the initial `array` state value, otherwise if there is nothing stored in localStorage `null` will be computed value and the `|| []` will return an empty array (`[]`) as the initial `array` state value.

Comment: I tried this useEffect but when I go to SIgnIn page and back to register page, it refreshes array back to 0 in localStorage

Comment: @MohammadFaateh This is because the component remounts and the initial `array` state is an empty array (`[]`). If you are persisting state to localStorage then you probably want to initialize state from localStorage. If you need help with this I can update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @MohammadFaateh Done. Please check the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you also please explain this code? i'd be really grateful

Comment: The code that you updated. I have a question. what value will localstorage get and store it in initialState.
And second what does this statement mean 'JSON.parse(initialState || []'?

Comment: @MohammadFaateh Ok, added a brief explanation, hopefully that makes clear what the initializer function is doing.

Comment: Sir one other problem arose. When i register the first user, it stores empty array in localStorage. When i store second user, it stores first user in array in localStorage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234394/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-mohammad-faateh).